# Generating multiple PDF documents from spreadsheet and images

Tags: pdf, images, documentation-generator, spreadsheet

I am looking for a free or low cost product that i can use to quickly create multiple PDF documents populated with text and images from a spreadsheet.

I have a background image which will the a common asset between all documents, a folder of images which have been numbered, and a spreadsheet with text i would like to populate the document with.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so i can quickly generate documents ready for printing.

EDIT: Each document will have a common background. Each document will also have 1 image, and around 5-10 few short pieces of text which will be unique to each document.

I currently run Windows 10, but i have access to virtual machines running any free operating system, such as linux. I also have a WAMP web server if that helps.

Comment: What is the input file format? You just say spreadsheet. Is it Microsoft Excel's .xslx file?

Comment: What kind of volume? Dozens or thousands of pages? Also, what is your budget?

Answer (score 1):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable, [Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) can be used to import content from Excel and generate PDF documents.

You need to write code (C# or any .NET language) to extract the data from the Excel file (XlsIO is used for this: [sample code](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/xlsio/rangemanipulation.aspx)) and then creating the PDF documents by inserting the content ([sample code](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/invoice.aspx)).

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can do a small amount of programming as long as i have examples to follow so i'll give it a go.

Comment: You can also download the software and submit a [request](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac) to Syncfusion to provide a custom sample (free) and that can be a good starting point.